# MySQL SET query (x = x - y)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

In tables I have a field width type floor.

And when I do query in PHP, I want to minus from this value another number, for example:

```
$number = 14.3;
mysql_query("UPDATE field SET count = count - $number WHERE name = '$name');
```

I need to minus this `$number` from `count`, but query nothig do. I tried to put it into brackets, but the same result.

Comment: You need to end your query with "

Comment: $number = intval($number); then use it inside query `count` = (`count`-$number)

Comment: @Akam since `$number` is initially just being placed into a text string, there's no need to be concerned with how `PHP` views it. In either case it's just text by the time it gets to MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT` is a reserved keyword, try adding backticks. You also need to close your PHP code with double quotes.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE field SET `count` = `count` - $number WHERE name = '$name'");
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

if you don'e like to use backtick, an alternative is to supply an alias on the table.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE field a SET a.count = a.count - $number WHERE name = '$name'");
```

Comment: you have also a syntax error on your php code. add double quote at the end of `name = '$name'`

Comment: Double quote isn't important, all works perfect without it. For example if I minus just 1 from count, then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing double quote. Try this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE field SET `count` = `count` - $number WHERE name = '$name'");
```